# Just installed Python 3.12 but it doesn't work

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to clone a repo from GitHub and the 3rd step involves running Python3 pip install to install the requirements.

I didn't have python installed so I installed it using Winget with the command "Winget install python.python 3.12"

However, I'm still getting an error message telling me Python isn't installed.

After installing Python and retrying the command to install the requirement I got the error telling me Python wasn't installed.

I opened the start menu and saw the various pieces of Python that were installed, IDLE, Docs and Python 3.12 64bit. I opened both Python and IDLE and saw no errors.

So, I restarted, then opened the terminal and ran the command again: `python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt` but again it showed me the error with the message I could type "Python" to open the Microsoft Store and install from there.

Command and error below:
$> python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Edit: additional troubleshooting.
I tried python3 --version and got the python not installed error so I retried it with python -- version and it returned Python 3.12.1

So clearly it is installed but maybe not installed correctly as it doesn't appear under Python3?

Comment: download from https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Try `python` instead of `python3`